# My personal settings on OS X disappear after booting Windows (XP or 7) on my MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, windows, settings, bootcamp, startup

I installed Windows 7 (and XP before) on my MacBook Pro and whenever I boot my Windows and after that boot my OS X my clock shows the wrong time and **my login items that I set in the system preference > Accounts** disappear!

I have also lost my **second language added**! Indeed I lost all my specimen settings.

Someone told me that's because MBP don't have BIOS and that causes the problem to happen. Does anyone know how must I solve it?

P.S: asked this question before on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/162376/problem-after-installing-windows-xp-or-7-on-my-mackbook-pro) and get this answer about to edit registry and set RealTimeIsUniversal to 1.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation

but it just solve the time problem.

this is my login items but I don't think it related to apps was set here because I changed them many times and still have the problem.

[image]

Comment: If you reboot OS X without booting in Windows, do the login items disappear? I can't see why booting to Windows would mess up the Mac OS X login items.

Comment: no it won't disappear, if I directly boot my os x.

Comment: can you update your post with the list of your login items?

Answer (score 2):

Try to backup and delete the file under `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist`

This will remove the login item you have and Mac OS X will create a new (clean) one.

For more information:

- Do you by any chance use some kind of app cleaner on your Mac that would delete `.plist` files?
- When on Windows, do you mount your Mac partition with read access?

Comment: I try this later and inform you the result.

Answer (score 0):

**About the time :**

You have to tell Windows that the clock is UTC.

To do this, edit the following in the registry :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
 SYSTEM
  CurrentControlSet
   Control
    TimeZoneInformation
     RealTimeIsUniversal
```

and set it to a `DValue` of 1.

Comment: this just solve time issue and some one on superuser told me how solve other problem?

Comment: What's the point with the clock setting ? I don't see how they're related.

Comment: I just want said that this registry solve the clock issue not the problem about I lost my login items that I set in the system.

Comment: Ok … So you should probably change the title of your question as I'm pretty sure that the clock settings are not related to the lost of login items.

Comment: Actually, I believe you should post another question about the login. And accept this answer for the wrong date issue.

Comment: as I edit my question I explain that the date issue was solved before in superuser I just copy & paste my question from there, and also I changed my title, Sorry for any inconvenience caused.

Comment: Like the person told you on Super User, you've got two problems, so you've got to ask two questions.
Since the time problem is solved, **remove it (the registry hack) from this question**. This led @studer to think you still had a time difference problem and might fool other people too.